How To Uninstall Anchor?
My anchor keyfiles are messed up I think, and it's not solved with anchor clean so I want to completely uninstall the anchor-cli.
When I run which anchor I see that it is installed via cargo:
/Users/jim/.cargo/bin/anchor

But when I try to uninstall it with the command cargo uninstall anchor I get this error:
cargo uninstall anchor
error: package ID specification `anchor` did not match any packages


You can use the following to sync your keys;
anchor keys sync

But if you really want to uninstall Anchor, you should use AVM
avm uninstall 0.30.2

More details here
Anchor Lang Docs

You can remove target folder
rm -rf target/

After remove, rebuild
anchor build

Then it will generate new key
I think you don't need to reinstall anchor
